# Rest Api calls restricted after specific time

Tags: java, cron, timeout, scheduler

I need to implement something like a timeout for a http request on a ticketing application.
Let's say someone create a POST request and a new ticket is created.

The issue is, we are only integrated with another ticketing tool and after the Post request is called, we just receive an acknowledge response by the other ticketing tool.. something like " we received your request and we will handle it later".

They response with an actual ticket id by calling a PATCH and thus, we will receive the final ticket id.

However, we should restrict the timline in wichi they are allowed to response. For example, if they call the patch after we did the Post request 10 minutes ago, let's suppose it is too late and the ticket should be invalid and they shouldn't be allowed to update the ticket with ticket id anymore.

Is there a way we can do this in java?

Answer (score 0):

By tickets you mean support tickets? It sounds like a strange ticketing tool you're calling. Just so I understand correctly: you receive a call to create a ticket or something, and you call another ticketing tool to create a ticket, but it doesn't respond to your request immediately? Instead, it sends your application a webhook once it's processed your request?

If that's correct then I imagine you would maintain a local database of the tickets you've created, or at least the requests you've sent the external service, because you'd need to look up against this to process the webhook from the other ticketing tool. So you can just store a timestamp in your local database, compare the time of the webhook against that timestamp, and reject it if it exceeds 10 minutes or so.